# Running "ng" causes "Unexpected token ..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

When I run ng with any command, then causes

> ng -v

```
C:\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:16
constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

node -v
v6.10.0

npm -v
4.4.1

I tried reinstalling the node, npm and  @angular/cli. No solution has helped.

@Edited, Solution

I deleted ng, ng.cmd from C:\nodejs\ and folders @angular/cli/, angular-cli/ fromC:\nodejs\node_modules, and reinstall @angular/cli, and then 
works correctly.

Comment: Follow the commands  1.npm install -g angular-cli  2.ng new [app_name] 3.ng serve

Comment: clean your npm cache and install latest typescipt

Comment: @GauravChaudhary: I also tried this solution

Comment: Have you installed angular-cli ,npm,node ,typescript globally

Comment: @VenkateswaranR Of course

Comment: check if you have added your angular-cli\bin path to the path variable after adding restart the visual studio